# Stripe Error: must provide source or customer

Tags: forms

I am fairly new to wordpress dev and I am trying to include a stripe checkout form to a custom page I developed from scratch. I followed stripe's documentation on how to do this: [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges]
Here is my html page

```
<?php
    
    /* Template Name: Custom Checkout Page  */
    
    /**
    * Page template
    *
    * @package mytheme
    */
    
    //exit if accessed directly
    if (! defined('ABSPATH')){
        exit;
    }
    
    get_header();
    ?>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  


  </head>
    
   
<body>
     <form action="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/{my_theme}/charge.php" method="post "id="payment-form" name="payment-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="stripecn">Card Number *</label>
            
                        <div id="stripecn">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
        
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="stripexpd">
                                        Expiry Date
                                    </label>
                                    <div id="stripexpd">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="stripecc">
                                        Card Code (CVC)
                                    </label>
                                    <div id="stripecc">
                                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
    
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    <div class="form-group" id="buttonHolder">
    
     <button class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit Stripe Payment</button>
     </div>
     </form>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/includes/client.js"></script>
</body>
```

next is my client.js :

```
// Set your publishable key: remember to change this to your live publishable key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_asjdfmykeyhereu129123j');
var elements = stripe.elements();



// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('cardNumber', {
    classes : {
        base: "form-control",
        invalid:"error"
    }
    
    
    
});

var cardexp = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
    classes : {
        base: "form-control",
        invalid:"error"
    }
    
    
    
});

var cardcvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
    classes : {
        base: "form-control",
        invalid:"error"
    }
    
    
    
});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#stripecn');
cardexp.mount('#stripexpd');
cardcvc.mount('#stripecc');

// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
   
    }
  });
});

function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
 
  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

NOW this is my charge.php file :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(

'sk_test_9823jMysecretkey0123j'
);

// Token is created using Stripe Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => 999,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'description' => 'Example charge',
  'source' => $token,
  
]);
```

I also uploaded the stripe php library into themes_folder->plugin->vendor/

now when I make a test transaction the form submits and goes into a blank page but no test payments done on my stripe dashboard.
when I check my wordpress server for errors here's what I get:

> 2021/04/08 02:03:05 [error] 81674#81674: *206783 FastCGI sent in
> stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined index: stripeToken in
> /www/sitefolder/public/wp-content/themes/theme/charge.php
> on line 12PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request
> req_xXLp0z05PAdsSS) Must provide source or customer. thrown in
> /www/sitefolder/public/wp-content/themes/theme/plugin/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php
> on line 38" while reading response header from upstream, client:
> my.ip.address, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/themes/theme/charge.php?stripeToken=tok_1IdnD2BVqVZ2ueLqOCdmo6Nv
> HTTP/1.0", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.3-fpm-mysite.sock:", host:
> "www.example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/"

Comment: Hi Dale,
It looks like you have implemented the code correctly and I havent been able to locate any typos or discrepencies with your code. Maybe give the below link a try and see if that helps! :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334841/1473559

Comment: Hi, I fixed this, it was a type error on the form method="post " there was a space lol fixed it by removing said space

Answer (score 1):

error was in the `form method='post '` having a space I just deleted the space thanks to sir @kirill for pointing that out